# SED, Getting the last file name

Tags: bash, sed, quartz-composer

It is a SED issue.

I am working in Quartz Composer (Mac OSX) script to:

1. Open the last .log from a directory.
2. Getting the last text line of that file and remove its 24 first characters.
3. Show the last line each time a new one is created inside the last .log

I think this would be so simple. At this moment, I have this done in QC, and it is almost working. But I have issues with the SED commands in both *getFileName.sh* and *getLastLineOfLog.sh*

*getFileName.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/Me/
/bin/echo `ls -tr *.log | tail -1`
```

What I need here is to open the last .log file, with this name structure *127.0.0.1,NUMBER.log* being the NUMBER section a 5 digits number. The higher the number, the newer the .log file. Now, it opens just the first .log file.

Do you know how to write in SED the right commands for doing that, please?

*getLastLineOfLog.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/tail -1 /Users/Me/$1 | sed 's/^.\{24\}//' > /Users/Me/$1.log
echo `/usr/bin/tail -1 /Users/Me/$1.log`
```

In this second file, I have tried to get the last file of the loaded .log and echo it without its 24 first characters. It works, but creating a new .log.log. (etc.) file each time the function passes, thing that I would like to avoid.

Is it necessary to output the results of the SED commands to a new file? How could it be done as simple as possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to sort by the filename:

```
ls *.log | sort -t, -k2 -n | tail -1
```

Comment: Thank you very much vlabrecque.

Answer (score 1):

getFileName.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/Me/
ls -tr *.log | tail -1
```

You don't need the `echo`, as that `echo` outputs its arguments.

getLastLineOfLog.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/tail -1 /Users/Me/$1 | sed 's/^.\{24\}//'
```

Similarly here, you already have just the last line, so you don't need another `tail`.

EDIT:
In fact you can get rid of the tail as well, by doing it in sed:

getLastLineOfLog.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -ne'$s/^.\{24\}//p' /Users/Me/$1
```

Comment: ls -tr will sort by the modification time, not the filename.

Comment: Do `ls -rtl` to check that the modification time; I guess they don't match the filename order.

Comment: Hi Douglas, thank you for your answer. But now in the first case, it is working like before, loading the first and not the last file. I.e. I have 127.0.0.1,50454.log and 127.0.0.1,50604.log, and it opens the first one. I need to open the last .log file. Do you know how to arrange that SED commands to open the last .log files? Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, I have tried ls -rtl *.log | tail -1 and it outputs "Not such file or directory".

Comment: Then you don't have any *.log files in that directory.

Comment: Ok, it´s working now,! As I have been working on modifying the .logs by hand, the issue was the modification time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very old question, but here are two ways to get the last file in a bash only way and without pipes:

- First method:

  ```
  : * && echo $_
  ```

  The `man bash` says:

  > `$_` expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion.

  So here you're executing the command `:` (does nothing) with all the files as arguments and then you're getting the last of them with `$_`.
- Second method:

  ```
  for lastfile in *; do : ; done
  echo "$lastfile"
  ```

  In this way you're doing nothing but assigning each file to `lastfile` so, at the end, you'll have the last file (*alphabetically talking*) saved in `lastfile`.